# Android deep linking path patterns

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to ask are question marks supported in deep linking path patterns?

Right now if I have a link https://blah.com/test?key=123

`<data android:pathPattern="/test.*"/>` works but if I do

`<data android:pathPattern="/test?key=.*"/>` or

`<data android:pathPattern="/test.key=.*"/>`

the deep linking doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`pathPattern` works only with path like this `/.*/.*/`.
The query parameters ('key') will be accessible through the Intent `intent.getData()`

Answer (score 0):

No, the `?key=...` is not part of the URI path. It is called the query.